# Signal handling in C with process and 2 threads doesn't work

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I am working with the following example (which is based on the example in the manpage for pthread_sigmask in linux):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Simple error handling functions */

#define handle_error_en(en, msg) \
        do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

static void * silly_worker(void *arg)
{
  for(int index=0,max=5; index<max; ++index) {
    printf("waiting %d of %d\n",index,max);
    sleep(1);
  }
  puts("Finished waiting.  Here comes the SIGSEGV");
  strcpy(NULL,"this will crash");
}

static void *
sig_thread(void *arg)
{
    sigset_t *set = (sigset_t *) arg;
    int s, sig;

    for (;;) {
        s = sigwait(set, &sig);
        if (s != 0)
            handle_error_en(s, "sigwait");
        printf("Signal handling thread got signal %d\n", sig);
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_t thread2;
    sigset_t set;
    int s;

    /* Block SIGINT; other threads created by main() will inherit
       a copy of the signal mask. */

    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGQUIT);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGSEGV);
    s = pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, NULL);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_sigmask");

    s = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &sig_thread, (void *) &set);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create");

    /* Main thread carries on to create other threads and/or do
       other work */

    s = pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, &silly_worker, (void *) &set);
    if (s != 0)
        handle_error_en(s, "pthread_create");

    pause();            /* Dummy pause so we can test program */
}
```

According to the man page, this should catch the SIGSEGV generated by the silly_worker thread.  But it doesn't.  In fact I'm not sure what agency is getting the signal at all.  When the program runs, I get the following output:

```
waiting 0 of 5
waiting 1 of 5
waiting 2 of 5
waiting 3 of 5
waiting 4 of 5
Finished waiting.  Here comes the SIGSEGV
Segmentation fault
```

You can see that the signal handler doesn't output a "Segmentation fault" string, so it must be coming from the default handler.  If default, then it kind of spoils the purpose of the  example - to set a signal handler and capture signals and do something with them.

I can find a lot of examples of handlers, but none of them work for this situation:  none of them demonstrate a thread which causes a really obvious SIGSEGV, and catches and reports the error in its custom handler.

The question remains:  how does one get a custom signal handler to get the signal from this SIGSEGV'ing thread?

Comment: Does this work for other signals like SIGINT? Some signals like SIGSEGV and SIGILL are synchronous and are always delivered to the thread that caused them. I'm not sure if sigwait can handle these.

Comment: Note that "Segmentation fault" is generally printed by the shell when it sees your process was killed by a SIGSEGV signal.

Comment: It works for the other signals, but that won't help:  I'm trying to catch SIGSEGV specifically.  In a much shorter example with a single loop in main() and no threads, I can catch the SIGSEGV, no problem at all.  Its when threads come into play that it doesn't seem to work right.

Comment: Note that it would not work for other signals either if you sent them to a particular thread with `pthread_kill` or `raise`...

Answer (score 1):

The `SIGSEGV` from invalid memory accesses (as opposed to a "fake" one sent by `kill` or `sigqueue`) is sent to the thread that performed the invalid memory access, not to the whole process. Thus you cannot have a dedicated segfault-handler thread. If you want to handle it, you must handle it in the thread where it happened. (The reason you're seeing the shell print `Segmentation fault` is because, when `SIGSEGV` is blocked in the thread and a segfault occurs, the kernel performs the default action of killing the process. Actually it's UB per POSIX, but this is how Linux handles the UB.)

Note, however, that you could have the signal handler for `SIGSEGV` trigger an action by a dedicated thread. An ugly way to do this would be with another signal, which you could send (along with an argument) via `sigqueue`. The cleaner way (in my opinion, at least) to do it would be to have the `SIGSEGV` handler use `sem_post`, which is async-signal-safe and can be used to wake another thread waiting on a semaphore.

Comment: +1. You can't do this with SIGSEGV "If  SIGBUS,  SIGFPE,  SIGILL,  or  SIGSEGV are generated while they are
       blocked, the result is undefined, unless the signal  was  generated  by
       the kill(2), sigqueue(2), or raise(3).
"

Comment: So unlike every other signal type, sigsegv is always delivered to the triggering thread on Linux? That signals go to a random thread is usually the reason for having a dedicated signals thread with all other threads masked.

Comment: Signals sent to a process via `kill` or via a terminal (e.g. Ctrl-C) go to an arbitrary thread (among the set of threads with the signal not masked). These are *asynchronous* signals. Signals that occur as an immediate result of some action by the thread (like invalid memory accesses, writing to pipe or socket where the reading end is closed, etc.) are *synchronous* signals and go to the thread whose behavior generated them.